# Google Apps Script: code to convert a text document in PDF?

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script, google-data-api

I'd like a snipe of code to convert a google docs text document template in a PDF file. I know how to create a new document as a google text document, but not how to transform it in a PDF file.
I find this piece of code:

```
var pdf = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="+key+"&exportFormat=pdf&gid=1&gridlines=0&printtitle=0&size=7&fzr=true&portrait=1&fitw=1", requestData).getBlob().setName(name);

  return pdf;
```

But I don't need spreadsheet customization (actually, I don't need spreadsheet, but text file).

How can I can do it? Only with `UrlFetchApp.fetch` class?

One more question: can I automaticaly send this PDF file to be printed after I've created it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly your question is about getting a text document as pdf ?

There is a dedicated method for that :

`DocsList.getFileById('document ID').getAs('application/pdf');`

see [related documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file?hl=fr-FR#getAs%28String%29)

Comment: Nowasdays DocList is deprecated. Instead use `DriveApp`