# Script running fine in a sheet, not in another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, urlfetch, google-data-api

I have two sheets, both of them in a shared drive. Both have the very same script to send html emails based upon a Google Doc (also located in the shared drive) : first I get the html code, and then send the mail.

Everything runs fine in a sheet, but I get a 404 if I run it in the other sheet.

I first thought of a permissions issue, but I ran it from two different accounts, and I have the same behavior. The odd thing is that this script used to run absolutely fine...

Here's the script :

```
function docToHtml(templateId){
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id="+templateId+"&exportFormat=html";
  var param = 
      {
        method      : "get",
        headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
        muteHttpExceptions:false,
      };
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText();
  return html;
}
```

Well, as it runs fine in one of the sheets, the script must not be the culprit. I've tried to figure this out, but I am out of thoughts.

Comment: Are there any differences between the sheets? Is the data the same?

Comment: @Kessy No, the sheets are not the same and they contain different data. What I've tried was to make a brand new sheet, copy the code and try it. But again, I get this 404, or even worse, a 401. As I said, it used to work seamlessly. Any thouhgt where I could search ?

Comment: How are you calling the `docToHtml`? Are you sure that the `templateId` is actually an spreadsheet valid Id? Have you already tried using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled?

Comment: @Rubén when someone answers a form, the data is inserted in a sheet. This sheet then sends a customized html mail to that person. The 'docToHtml' function is called in that script. I've tried the following : get the link generated by this function (the 'url' var) and paste it in the browser. Works fine. But when executed by the script, no success. I will try your suggestions. I've read your 2nd link, interesting one, with quite the same behavior as I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 404 means "Not found" so it's possible that the spreadsheet id is wrong or the OAuth credentials that you are using hasn't permission to access the corresponding files.

If you are calling the function from dialog or sidebar maybe the wrong credentials are being passed to the server side script.

Another possibility is that the script scopes doesn't include one of those that allow to access a file hosted in Google Drive<sup>1</sup>.

NOTES:

1. This possibility was confirmed by the OP through a comment to this answer.

---

If you are open to use an alternative, I suggest you to use `DriveApp` or `Drive` instead of Google Documents (DATA) API as nowadays there aren't official reference doc about

```
GET /feeds/download
```

Anyway there are a lot of questions using similar forms i.e.

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheet/export/Export?=...
https://spreadsheet.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheet/export/Export?=...
```

Related

- [Google Apps Script: code to convert a text document in PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20256517/1595451)
- [URL fetch sometimes leads to "Uncaught ScriptError" resp. 404](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31651221/1595451)
- [Sending attachment in Word format does not work in Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59609648/1595451)

Comment: The second link provided in this answer solved the problem, thanks @rubén

Comment: @Romain You are welcome. By the way, adding `DriveApp.getRootFolder()` made `GET /feeds/download/...`works because it adds the scope required to access files hosted in Google Drive.